# If $p:A\to B$ and $q:C\to D$ are quotient maps, $B$ and $C$ locally compact, separable spaces, is $p\times q$ a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

It is a true or false question from an old test.

At first I tried some counterexamples, using the line with two origins or taking $B$ as a quotient space of the real line by some not-open subset, since I know the result is true if $B$ and $C$ are also Hausdorff spaces. It did not work.

I then tried to prove it instead, showing that $(p\times q)^{-1}(U)$ open implies $U$ open, but I can't work out how to use both hypothesis, or any other way to reach the answer.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It also works for locally compact spaces which are not Hausdorff. If $Z$ is a locally compact space and $p:X\to Y$ is a quotient map, then $p\times\mathbf 1_Z:X\times Z\to Y\times Z$ is a quotient map. One way to show this is by verifying the universal property of quotient maps, and here you have to use the adjunction $\mathbf{Top}(Y\times Z,W)\cong\mathbf{Top}\left(Y,W^Z\right)$, which holds when $Z$ is locally compact. One can also show directly that $p\times\mathbf 1_Z$ is a quotient map, this is done by Ronald Brown in his book *Topology and Groupoids* on page 109.

Comment: I can't find Ronald Brown's book, can you give a hint in a way to prove any of the claims? I assume $Top(Y\times Z, W)$ is the topology of $Y\times Z$ glued in $W$, right? I have not seen the notation before.

Comment: @VladmirSicca: Put $q=p×1_Z$. Assume that $W=q^{-1}(q(W))$ (if $W$ is the preimage of its image, we call it *saturated*) and that $W$ open. We want to show that $q(W)$ is open in $Y×Z$. So take a $(p(x_0),z_0)\in q(W)$. Then $(x_0,z_0)\in W$. Let $Z_0$ be the subset of $Z$ such that
$$\{x_0\}×Z_0=\{x_0\}×Z∩W$$
Then $Z_0$ is a neighborhood of $z_0$, so it contains a compact neighborhood $C$ of $z_0$. Now let
$$U=\{x∈X\mid\{x\}×C⊆W\}$$
so $U×C\subseteq W$. The plan is to show that $U$ is open and saturated with respect to $p$. That would imply that $p(U)×C⊆q(W)$ is a neighborhood of $(x_0,z_0)$.

Comment: And $Top(Y\times Z,W)$ is the set of maps from $Y\times Z$ to $W$. We can also make that into a space. The space $W^Z$ has as elements all maps from $Z$ to $W$, and the topology is generated by the sets
$$W(C,U)=\{f:Z\to W\mid f(C)\subseteq U\}$$
where $C$ ranges over all compact subsets of $Z$ and $U$ ranges over the open subsets of $W$. This is called the *compact-open* topology.